# Calculating Adjacency Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the concept, I know it is pretty simple but could someone help me out.

Assume that I have the following:

$V = \begin{bmatrix}
 0&0&1 \\ 
 0&0&1 \\ 
 1&0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$

This is an undirected graph, now I want to find the Adjacency matrix, which, is all the elements that are in the set.

So I will have

$V \in V = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}(v1, v1), (v1, v2), (v1, v3), (v2, v2), (v2, v1) ......
\end{matrix}\right.$

I don't understand this however, in the formula, it says to put a "1" it's in the subset.. However, do I put a 1 if it's in the subset WHERE the value is "1" in the matrix $V$ or is "1" put where only the subset can exist.. I.e. $(v1, v1)$ would therefore have "0"?

Thanks

EDIT:

In this example, the following is given:

`G = [0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1; 1, 1, 0];
 xy = [1 1; 0 0 ; 2 0];`

Therefore, what does `xy` represent in this example, if `G` is the adjacency matrix? I'm guessing that it represents the edges, but, I don't know how to calculate these for a given matrix.

Comment: Do you mean $V$ is the adjacency matrix and you want to find the graph?

Comment: @GitGud Hey, no! Sorry $A = V\inV$ is the agency matrix. The formula says put 1 $if(v_{i}, v_{j}) \in E$ in this case it would be $V$ does this make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what $V\in V$ means nor how could the formula $V\in V$ represent a matrix. I think $V$ is the adjacency matrix and you need to get the graph which was 5xum did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is the adjacency matrix, then the graph has verices $\mathcal V=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and edges $\mathcal E = \{(v_1,v_3), (v_2,v_3), (v_3,v_1)\}$

Comment: Hey thanks. I don't understand how this relates to the edges though. Surely, with the formula I'm using where it says place "1" where $\in$ in the adjacency matrix and 0 if it not.. Surely, the vertices that you gave would just produce the same matrix?

Comment: If you produce a graph from an andjacency matrix, then construct an adjacency matrix from that graph, you will get the same matrix back, is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, sorry. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Question" ^^ Sorry